# How to set images after the names in Kendo drodpdown list?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have used Html.Kendo.DropDownList, i want to add edit and delete image at the right hand side of each text.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("PrefernceNameList")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .Events(e => e.Change("prefernceNameChange"))
              .BindTo(ViewBag.PrefernceNames)
              .Value(Model.DefaultPreference)
```

How would i modify the template to achieve the same ?

Comment: are you expecting the images to do anything or just display edit/delete images?

Comment: i want to handle the click event of images

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display images next to the item content and selected text, then you will need to use `Template` and `ValueTemplate` options:

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DropDownListBuilder#methods-ValueTemplate(System.String)

Check the online demo that shows how to use them:

- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/template

Comment: when i am using      $("#KendoPrefernceNameList").kendoDropDownList values in the dropdown are displayed as [object object]

Comment: Did you define dataValueField/dataTextField? Check demos:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index